# Finding the values of a & b that will give equivalent zeros for two polynomials.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the zeros of the polynomial $(x^2 -2x + a)$ are also two of the zeros of the polynomial $(2x^3 +bx^2 +6x -2)$.

This problem has to do with the remainder and factor theorems for polynomials. What I know:

If $P(\alpha) = 0$, then $P(x)$ has $(x-\alpha)$ as a factor.

$R = P(\alpha)$ if the polynomial $P(x)$ has been divided by $x-\alpha$ until the remainder $R$ is independent  of x.

What I don't know:

- The application of these theorems to solve this problem. More specifically: where do I start?

Is it possible? Plugging it into Desmos and messing with the values of a and b makes me think that it isn't possible at all. I'm not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify
$$ (x^3+bx^2+6x-2)-x\cdot(x^2-2x+a)-(b+4)\cdot(x^2-2x+a)$$
and contemplate what that tells you

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help but I'm not really sure I understand. I expanded it and got -2x^2 +2bx -ab -ax -4a +14x -2.